# Would SSRS be an ideal tool to create a user interface for MSSQL procedures in retrieving backend data?

Tags: mysql, user-interface, reporting-services, backend

I managed to create a typical SSRS report by building one through MSSQL BI development environment. I used a simple procedure to retrieve a list of databases that reside on our SQL servers. My question would be...would SSRS allow me to build a native UI app in displaying SQL procedure results in a more user friendly way?

For instance, I am currently manually running procedures to retrieve information about our backend systems, and I wonder whether SSRS would be an ideal tool to automate the process by allowing a user to view the information that the procedures produce in a more user friendly way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about your question, when you ask (emphasis mine):

> would SSRS allow me to build a **native UI app** in displaying SQL procedure results

In any case, SSRS isn't meant for nor very good at functioning as an "App" with proper UI/UX. If you're just after *basic* features for letting the user pick a stored procedure and then *reporting* the results back to the user SSRS may suit your needs.

You continue:

> I wonder whether SSRS would be an **ideal** tool to automate the process by allowing a user to view the information that the procedures produce in a **more user friendly way**?

Whether it's "ideal" really depends on your context.

Finally, the last bit is somewhat confusing: "more" than what? Running queries directly in SSMS? Then probably yes.

Bottom line: if you stick with using SSRS for *reporting* purposes (possibly interactive, to a certain degree), then SSRS *may* be the ideal tool for your case.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thanks for the input. I am looking for something that has basic features in reporting the results back to the user when the procedures are picked. To your second point, yes, I am wondering whether SSRS would be more user friendly than running queries in SSMS. Again, thanks for the input. Lastly, would you happen to know any resources that I could look at for developing something basic?

Comment: @ShaunK in that case SSRS seems to be okay for your task. For resources I guess any tutorial site you like may help, if all else fails there's always the [MSDN tutorials on SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522859.aspx). Good luck.